# Document variables not recognized by fields. Acrobat Pro

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I hope this is the right place for this question. I have been trying to set up a simple document that calculates fields based on other fields with the same document. I am attempting to create a list of variables to make scripting faster. right now my document script looks like this

```js
var lv = this.getField("Level").value;


var s = this.getField("StrB").value;


var d = this.getField("DexB").value;

var c = this.getField("ConB").value;

var int = this.getField("IntB").value;

var w = this.getField("WisB").value;

var ch = this.getField("ChaB").value;

var ss = this.getField("Str").value;

var ds = this.getField("Dex").value;

var cs = this.getField("Con").value;

var ints = this.getField("Int").value;
```

and so on.
This is an example of a script using these variables

```
{
event.value = strBonus + pb;
}
```

This returns nothing. Not even a warning. I double-checked my spelling and names. I am sure this is a formatting issue as I am a novice and don't fully understand the language. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time in reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define and initialise a variable in a document level script, they get the field value at that time (and that's normally blank).

So, in order to simplify things, define the variables as Field Objects, such as in

```
var lv = this.getField("Level") ;
```

In the calculation, you will then retrieve the field value as, for example, in

```
var lv1 = lv.value * 5 ;
```

And that should do it.

About documentation: You will need the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK documentation, downloadable from the developer section of the Adobe website.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, Max. It didn't work on my old file but when I created a blank document and made test fields, the variable worked as designed. I also want to thank you for showing me the great resource at Adobe. Now I have a lot of reading to do! Thanks again!